# How to output notify callback when user git_merge failed in libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

I 'm trying to pull from a repo with libgit2.

My steps are these:

I use git_remote_fetch to down remote origin data and the return OK.

after I use git_merge API.
The questio is two users modify the same area of the same file, libgit2 will report content conflicts. This status is OK.

Next I just delete local file 'a.txt', At the same times I just modify remote branch file 'b.txt'.  And set a notify_cb in my git_checkout_options, and set notify_flags to include GIT_CHECKOUT_NOTIFY_CONFLICT|GIT_CHECKOUT_NOTIFY_ALL. As result git_merge just return error code is '-13', No output conflict files name. How to get the conflict files name from notify callback, when merge failed?

```
git_merge_options checkout_opt = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTINS_INIT;
git_checkout_options checkout_opt = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INT;
checkout_opt.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE | GIT_CHECKOUT_ALLOW_CONFLICTS;
checkout_opt.notify_flags = GIT_CHECKOUT_NOTIFY_ALL | GIT_CHECKOUT_NOTIFY_CONFLICT;
checkout_opt.notify_cb = git_checkout_notify_cb // git_checkout_notify_cb is myself write callback.

int error = git_merge(repo, &their_head[0],1, &merge_opt, &checkout);
if(error<0)
{
   //Just output error code -13. no call notify callback.
}
```